# Ring of remainders definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers, euclidean-domain

My notes on Euclidean domains state a notion of ring of remainders that I should connect with the quotient by certain ideal but I don't see quite how the connection is done.

> Given an euclidean domain $D$ with unique quotient and remainder
>   defined and $m \in D \setminus \{0\}$, we define the ring of
>   remainders $D_m$ as the set $\{R_m(a):a \in D\}$ together with operations
>   $a+b = R_m(a+b)$ and $ab = R_m(ab)$.

Where $R_m$ is the function that gives the unique euclidean remainder of the division by $m$. This is done having in mind $K[X],\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then, the notes continue stating that $R_m:D \to D_m$ is an homomorphism and therefore $D/mD \cong D_m$.

However, I'm missing properties for $R_m$ to be a ring homomorphism. For instance, $R_m(1)$ does not need to be $1$ as in $\mathbb{Z}$, $(-1)(-1) = 1$ and $R_m(1) = 0$ (where we assume that remainder in $\mathbb{Z}$ is unique, when defined as positive).

Have you encountered anything similar to this before? The only similar text I can find is [this](https://books.google.es/books?id=J53qAlCYoG4C&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=ring%20of%20remainders&source=bl&ots=J-U2o-4BqY&sig=v5H0biKwy5T48DJzWyJTq39X-GM&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNkMGsqtvYAhVE1xQKHXOVCtsQ6AEINjAB#v=onepage&q=ring%20of%20remainders&f=false).

Comment: It's simply the quotient of $R$ by the principal ideal $mR$ – a generalisation of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: What is $A$, exactly?

Comment: Oh! It's clearer now. Well $R_m(1)=1$ if the modulus is a non-unit. The difference between $D_m$ and $D/mD$ is the former is the canonical set of representatives of the congruence classes

Comment: @Bernard therefore, I have to remove $m \in U(D)$ as a possibility. but in the other case, $m \notin U(D)$ then $1 = mq+r$ with $\phi(r) < \phi(m)$ where $\phi$ is the euclidean function and i still need to prove that $r = 1$.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $r$ is 1 or not. $1\equiv r\pmod{m}$, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @jgon but note that with these congruence you're working with $D/mD$ you're not saying anything about the ring of remainders $R_m$ as explained in my question.

Comment: I realize that probably the solution is to further guarantee that $\phi(1) < \phi(m)$ (something that happens in $\mathbb{Z}_n, K[X]$.

Comment: @Rodrigo With congruence I'm not working with $D/mD$, I'm working with $D$. Congruence is an equivalence relation on $D$, and $D/mD$ is the ring of equivalence classes. The point I'm making is that even if $R_m(1)\ne 1$, it behaves like 1 in $D_m$, so it doesn't matter. I expanded on my comment in the answer I wrote below. Perhaps its unclear, but you haven't requested clarification, so I can't know how to improve it.

Comment: @jgon let me think on everything that you said, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $R_m(q)\equiv q\pmod{m}$, for any $q\in D$, so the map $\phi:D_m\to D/mD$ given by $R_m(q)\mapsto [R_m(q)]=[q]$, the equivalence class of $R_m(q)$ in $D/mD$ is well defined. Then by definition of addition, $\phi(a+b)=[R_m(a+b)]=[a+b]=[a]+[b]=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$. Similarly
$\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. Then since $\phi$ is a bijection and preserves addition and multiplication, this identifies $D_m$ with $D/mD$, so $D_m$ must have a unit $a$ given by $\phi(a)=[1]$, note that $\phi(R_m(1))=[1]$, so $R_m(1)$ is the unit regardless of whether or not its equal to 1.